# If account manager is changes on account, how to update any open renewals ownership to that account manager on Opportunity object?

Tags: admin, system-admin, developer-org

If account manager is changes on account, how to update any open renewals ownership to that account manager on Opportunity object?

I start creating a record-triggered flow, and I'm stuck on adding elements that that makes sense. What are the steps to creating this in Salesforce flow?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

After your `Find Open Renewals` 'Get Records' element, you need to loop through each of those records, set the new owners, and then update the records with an 'Update Records' element.

There's a little complexity because you'll need to create a new record variable and a record collection variable to use in the loop. Look at this [Flow Element: Loop](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_elements_loop_example.htm&type=5) example for direction.

Comment: thank you it was very helpful.